# How to linearise binary constraints

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to find a valid previous state in the game of life using linear programming.

This is what I have so far:

```
board = [[0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0]]

width = len(board)
height = len(board[0])

rows = [str(i) for i in range(width)]
cols = [str(i) for i in range(height)]

choices = LpVariable.dicts("is_alive", (rows, cols), 0, 1, cat="Binary")
or_variables = LpVariable.dicts("OR_variable", (rows, cols), 0, 1, cat="Binary")

prob = LpProblem("Game_of_Life_reversal", LpMinimize)
prob += 0, "Arbitary Objective Function"

for r in rows:
    for c in cols:
        cell = choices[r][c]
        neighbours = getNeighbours(r,c, width, height, choices)
        if board[int(r)][int(c)] == 1:
            #If it's alive, and it was previously alive, then it must've had 2 or 3 neighbours
            #If it's alive, and it was previously dead, then it must've had 3 neighbours
            prob += lpSum(neighbours) >= 2 * cell + (1 - cell) * 3
            prob += lpSum(neigbours) <= 3
        else:
            #If it's dead, and was previously alive, then it must've had 0, 1 or 4+ neighbours
            #If it's dead, and was previously dead, then it must've had 0, 1, 2 or 4+ neighbours
            or_var = or_variables[r][c]
            prob += lpSum(neighbours) >= 4 * (1 - or_var)
            prob += lpSum(neighbours) <= cell * or_var + 9 * (1 - or_var) + or_var * (1 - cell) * 2
```

The last constraint `prob += lpSum(neighbours) <= or_var + 9 * (1 - or_var) + or_var * (1 - cell) * 2` is throwing `TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied`.

I'm guessing this is because I'm doing `or_var * (1 - cell) * 2` which violates linearity.

Is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Could you summarize your linear programming approach with math statements, please ? It's difficult to grasp it just looking at your code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look John. I've added some maths statements, I'm not sure if they're 100% correct as my maths isn't too strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that we have a grid n x n with. Our variables are 0 <= C(i , j) <= 1 for 1 <= i <= n and 1 <= j <= n.

Let C*(i , j) = sum of the variables associated to the neighbors of the cell (i , j).

For example, if the cell (i , j) is not a border:

C*(i, j) = C(i+1, j) + C(i-1, j) + C(i, j+1) + C(i, j-1) + C(i-1, j-1) + C(i-1, j+1) + C(i+1, j-1) + C(i+1, j+1).

If it's the upper left corner:

C*(1, 1) = C(1 , 2) + C(2 , 2) + C(2 , 1)

And so on.

---

1 ) For each cell (i, j) not in the border of the grid:

1.1) If the cell is now occupied:

3 - C(i, j) <= C*(i , j) <= 3

1.2) If the cell is now not occupied:

Let 0 <= x(i , j) <= 1,

4 * x(i , j) <= C*(i , j) <= 8 * x(i , j) + 2 - C(i , j)

---

2 ) For each cell (i , j) in the border of the grid:

2.1) If the cell is a corner:

2.1.1) If the cell is now occupied:

Use the same constraint of the item (1.1).

2.1.2) If the cell is now not occupied:

0 <= C*(i , j) <= 2 - C(i , j)

---

2.2) If the cell is an edge:

Same constraints of item (1).

---

Now you got n² contraints, plus at most n² - 4 contraints for the possibly defined x(i , j), plus n² contraints of the form 0 <= C(i , j) <= 1. All the contraints are linear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've implemented it and it seems to be working quite well.
I'm a bit confused about why constraint 1.2) works though. 

From my understanding when x(i,j) = 1 and C(i,j) = 0, then the upper bound for C*(i,j) would be  10 when in fact there can only ever be 8 neighbours for a cell.

Comment: The constraint (1.2) was the trickiest one . It got me thinking for some good time. The trick is to add a new variable but keep the constraint linear. In case (1.2), you have four possibilities. Also, you have an upper bound for the sum of neighbors, which is ensured by the constraints that the variables are between 0 and 1. With this info, you can write down the constraint I came up with. Try to write it on paper and see what are each of the four cases